# Why is `int >> 32` not always zero?

Tags: c++, c, bit-manipulation, shift

Can someone explain me why right 32 bitwise shift of some 4 byte integer number may return not zero in C/C++ ? Why does it depend on `-O` option of the compiler?

For example this code gives 45 with `-O0` and 0 with `-O3` options in gcc 4.8.3:

```
unsigned int x = 45; // 4 bytes
x = x >> 32;
printf("%u\n", x);
```

Why it is like this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Because it is undefined behavior: `[expr.shift]` says

> The behavior is undefined if the right operand is negative, or greater than or equal to the length in bits of the promoted left operand.

As for the *specific* undefined behavior, I imagine it is as follows:

- With `-O0`, it compiled to actually perform a right shift in machine code, and on some machines (e.g. I believe x86 is such), shift functions only look at the low 5 bits of the shift amount when shifting a 32-bit word; shifting by 32 is the same as shifting by 0.
- With `-O3`, the compiler computed the constant itself, and just put `0` into the program rather than having it do a calculation.

You can check the assembly output to see if my prediction is right.

Comment: I expected the second behavior, however in my code that depends on this behavior and was compiled with -O3 flag, I do have non-zero results with 32 shifts. Maybe it's because the compiler performs -O3 optimization not uniformly. So, at the end of the day you can't rely on this. It is undefined as you said.

Comment: PS: but I think it is not right, it should be defined: bits coming from the left side should be zeros. Period. –