# Why is (2^31) >> 32 not 0?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, bit-shift

My problem is that

```
np.array([2**31], dtype=np.uint32) >> 32
```

does not return `0`, but returns `array([2147483648], dtype=uint32)` instead. The same is true for

```
np.right_shift(np.array([2**31], dtype=np.uint32), 32)
```

(so I believe this is simply how `>>` is implemented).

Interestingly, all these alternatives seem to work as expected, returning some kind of `0`:

```
print(
    2**31 >> 32,
    np.uint32(2**31) >> 32,
    np.array(2**31, dtype=np.uint32) >> 32,
    np.right_shift(2**31, 32),
    np.right_shift([2**31], 32),
    np.right_shift(np.uint32(2**31), 32),
    np.right_shift(np.array(2**31, dtype=np.uint32), 32),
)
```

In particular, what is different between Numpy arrays representing `2147483648` and `[2147483648]`?

I have seen this issue in JavaScript ([Why does << 32 not result in 0 in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24288111/why-does-32-not-result-in-0-in-javascript)) and C++ ([Weird behavior of right shift operator (1 >> 32)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3394259/weird-behavior-of-right-shift-operator-1-32), [Why is `int >> 32` not always zero?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31217053/why-is-int-32-not-always-zero)), but not yet in Python/Numpy. In fact, neither Python nor Numpy docs seem to be documenting this behavior:

- https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#shifting-operations
- https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.right_shift.html

Comment: That's quite strange ya, and i can't give you a reason for that, but note that doing `>> 31` returns you 1 and `<< 16` returns you 0 which are expected results. Maybe by doing `>> 32` it changes its type into a double or a thing like that

Comment: Actually any number shifted by >>32 remains the same. 
So `np.array([123], dtype=np.uint32) >> 32` equals `np.array([123], dtype=np.uint32)`
And even more `(np.array([123], dtype=np.uint32) >> 33)` equals `(np.array([123], dtype=np.uint32) >> 1)`
Really not expected.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While not documented, numpy is mostly implemented in C and the shift operator in C (and C++) is not defined for shifts greater than or equal to the number of bits. So the result can be arbitrary.

If you look at the types of the examples that work you'll see why they work:

```
print(
    type(2**31 >> 32),
    type(np.uint32(2**31) >> 32),
    type(np.array(2**31, dtype=np.uint32) >> 32),
    type(np.right_shift(2**31, 32)),
    np.right_shift([2**31], 32).dtype,
    type(np.right_shift(np.uint32(2**31), 32)),
    type(np.right_shift(np.array(2**31, dtype=np.uint32), 32)),
)
```

> <class 'int'> <class 'numpy.int64'> <class 'numpy.int64'> <class 'numpy.int64'> int64 <class 'numpy.int64'> <class 'numpy.int64'>

The first uses Python's own `int` type, while the others are all converted to `numpy.int64`, where the behavior for a 32-bit shift is correct.
This is mostly due to the fact that scalar (zero-dimensional) arrays behave differently. And in the `list` case that the default integer type for numpy is *not* `numpy.uint32`.

On the other hand

```
print((np.array([2**31], dtype=np.uint32) >> 32).dtype)
```

> uint32

So you run into the undefined behavior here.

Comment: As `type(np.uint32(2**31)` is numpy.int64, so `np.array(2**31, dtype=np.uint32) >> 64` will give non zero again.

Comment: @LeonidMednikov yes, if you start shifting those 64-bit integers by 64 bits or more you will run into similar issues.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, good idea to look at types. I get that the observed effect *may be* due to undefined behavior, but should it be undefined at all? Shouldn't the definition of the language be independent of its implementation? In other words, shouldn't at least the definition (= documentation) of the language be amended?

Comment: @bers I agree. This is either a documentation or an implementation bug.

Comment: Or at the very least a leaky abstraction

Comment: "This is mostly due to the fact that scalar (zero-dimensional) arrays behave differently." This is true independent of shifts - I was not aware of that: `(np.array(1, dtype=np.uint32) + 1).dtype` is `int64`, while `(np.array([1], dtype=np.uint32) + 1).dtype` is `uint32`. Got it.

Comment: @bers I think this should be considered a bug in NumPy so I have [reported it](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/13106).